# Accessing PHP methods using cronjob

Tags: php, linux, cron

Is there any way of getting Linux to run a particular method from a file?

At the moment I have this cronjob:

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php
```

But I want my script.php to hold several functions for different times:

```
public function ten_mins()
{
   $this->upkeep_function_1();
   $this->upkeep_function_2();
}

public function daily()
{
   $this->upkeen_function_3();
}
```

I want to avoid using wget or cURL because I want to avoid unnecessary TCP setups.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass arguments via the command-line using [`getopt()`](http://php.net/getopt) and act upon them in your script:

```
<?php
$options = getopt("f:hp:");
var_dump($options);
```

Running the above script with php script.php -fvalue -h will output:

```
array(2) {
  ["f"]=>
  string(5) "value"
  ["h"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: I understand why 'f' has a colon after it in `getopt()` (it's a required parameter, but why is it 'hp:' rather than just 'h:' What's the additional 'p' for?

Comment: @Jamie, `php script.php -fvalue -pyetanothervalue -h` ;-?

Answer (score 2):

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php ten_mins
```

PHP file...

```
public function ten_mins()
{
   $this->upkeep_function_1();
   $this->upkeep_function_2();
}

public function daily()
{
   $this->upkeen_function_3();
}

$method = end($_SERVER['argv']);
call_user_func($method);
```

Actually, it does seem like your initial code is missing parts, you can also call a method like this:

```
call_user_func(array($object, $method));
```

Comment: Please *don't* do this. Arbitrary code execution can still be harmful even when you think no one will use it because someone still is: you.

Comment: It's actually a bit better if you limit it to methods within a single class in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

How about getting the current date and time and then calling the appropriate function(s) based on that, perhaps using the `switch` command?

Answer (score 1):

split up your scripts into several files or execute some code inline with the commandline-option -r. here is the [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php)